# Rolling average of pandas data frame with multiple id's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe on which I am calculating the rolling average on over multiple id's.

```
df:
╔════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ value ║
╠════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║     2 ║
║  1 ║     5 ║
║  1 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║     4 ║
║  2 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║     5 ║
║  2 ║     3 ║
║  3 ║     6 ║
║  3 ║     5 ║
╚════╩═══════╝

Current Resulting df:
╔════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ value ║ average ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║     2 ║         ║
║  1 ║     5 ║ 3.5     ║
║  1 ║     1 ║ 3       ║
║  2 ║     4 ║ 2.5     ║
║  2 ║     1 ║ 2.5     ║
║  2 ║     5 ║ 3       ║
║  2 ║     3 ║ 4       ║
║  3 ║     6 ║ 4.5     ║
║  3 ║     5 ║ 5.5     ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════╝

Expected Resulting df:
╔════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ value ║ average ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║     2 ║         ║
║  1 ║     5 ║ 3.5     ║
║  1 ║     1 ║ 3       ║
║  2 ║     4 ║         ║
║  2 ║     1 ║ 2.5     ║
║  2 ║     5 ║ 3       ║
║  2 ║     3 ║ 4       ║
║  3 ║     6 ║         ║
║  3 ║     5 ║ 5.5     ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Right now my code does not take into account the change in id, so it will still take the average of the last 2 values. Is there anyway to take into account the change in id. 
My current code is `df['value'] = df['value'].df(window = 2, min_periods = 1).mean()`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

#### `concat` and `groupby`

```
pd.concat([d.rolling(2).mean() for _, d in df.groupby('id')])

    id  value
0  NaN    NaN
1  1.0    3.5
2  1.0    3.0
3  NaN    NaN
4  2.0    2.5
5  2.0    3.0
6  2.0    4.0
7  NaN    NaN
8  3.0    5.5
```